# Phonegap - Reload (resync) SD card ?

Tags: android, api, cordova

I am using Phonegap (Cordova), Android, and when I download a photo to my phone I have to reload the SD card in order for the photo to show up in the phones gallery.

Is there any way to resync the SD card within Phonegap without using a plugin that is native dependent?

Thanks.

I have been using this Java code to get the job done but I would like to be able to do this within Phonegap so it can be ported easier.

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://"
        + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

Answer (score 0):

i used this plugin

https://github.com/grnadav/SaveToPhotoAlbumPhonegapPlugin

but you are saying

**Is there any way to resync the SD card within Phonegap without using a plugin that is native dependent?**

phonegap calls the native code with javascript , so phonegap itself is native dependent.

correct me if i am wrong please.

thanks

Comment: Thanks, yes that plugin you refferenced is the code I posted in plugin form. What I was looking for was a phonegap API call so I don't have to write a plugin for every platform I want to port to.

Comment: Simon over at google groups clarified for me that this does have to done seperatly for each platform, but may only be an issue for android. https://groups.google.com/forum/m/?fromgroups#!topic/phonegap/AzbE0sLKPBk

Comment: Every API phonegap provides is created separately for each platform by their developers, so when you don't find what you need in phonegap API you have to create it by yourself for each platform.